# Is there a way to import all commits of a subversion repository to another repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

I've been developing a project on my local machine and had set up a local subversion repository for it. Its got 100s of commits from me so far.

However soon the project will be moving to a shared subversion repository hosted online and I'll be working from the new repository in future.

I'm wondering if there's a way to transfer my local repository to the new one or if my local repository is essentially useless from this point on?

The shared repo will be hosted on beanstalkapp.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dump an SVN repository and import it into the new location.
svnadmin instructions here: [svnadmin dump](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/dump/)

Beanstalk instructions for importing it here:
 [How can I prepare an SVN dump to import into BeanStalk](http://support.beanstalkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/68143-how-can-i-prepare-an-svn-dump-to-import-into-beanstalk-)
and here:
[Creating your subversion repository - Option 3: Upload a file](http://support.beanstalkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/68118-creating-your-subversion-repository)

Comment: To be fair the instructions on the Beanstalk page mentioned in the answer are brief to say the least. They link through to the Subversion book.